# Create Line in Highcharts with start and end point

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linear-regression

Please look at following example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

function recalculateUTCValue(startingUTC, add) {
    zeit = new Date(startingUTC);
    zeit.setDate(zeit.getDate()+add);
    return zeit;
}

function calcDateFromUTC(utc) {
    d = new Date(utc);
    return d;
}

function getDaysUntilEnd(utc) {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var endTime = calcDateFromUTC(utc);
    var diff =  Math.floor(( Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(currentTime) ) / 86400000);
    return diff;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var highchartsOptions   = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
var TaskChart; // Chart-Objekt
var container = $j('#chart01')[0];

var TaskDuration          = new Array();


var startingKW = 298;
// Save starting points to javascript variables for HighCharts
var startingUTC = 1288087223364;
// For a given time point id
var startTimePoint = 0;
var endTimePoint = 0;

TaskDuration =  [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,216.0,216.0,216.0,198.0,134.0,134.0,134.0,171.0,171.0,171.0,149.0,160.5,160.5,160.5];

// Get first value which is not "0"
var firstValue = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < TaskDuration.length; i++) {
    if(TaskDuration[i] != 0) {
        firstValue = i;
        break;
    }
}

// Get largest Y-Value; need for automatically zooming (setExtremes method)
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, TaskDuration);
var myStartDate;
var myEndDate;
// Check if we have a time point in the query
if(startTimePoint != 0) {
    var myStartDate = calcDateFromUTC(startTimePoint);
    var myEndDate = calcDateFromUTC(endTimePoint);
} else {
    // Otherwise we use the time of first created work item
    var myStartDate = recalculateUTCValue(startingUTC, firstValue); 
    var myEndDate = new Date();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    TaskChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    credits: {
            enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      renderTo: "chart01",
      defaultSeriesType: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x',
      events: {
          load: function(event) {
              this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(myStartDate, myEndDate);
              this.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0,largest);
          }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: "Task Burn Down Chart"
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            week: '%e. %b %Y'   
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            rotation: -60,
            x: 5,
            y: 15
        },
        offset: 10
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "Number of Hours"
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d.%m', this.x) +': '+ this.y;;            
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: { 
           stacking: 'normal',
           lineColor: '#666666',
           lineWidth: 1,
           marker: {
              lineWidth: 1,
              lineColor: '#666666'
           }
        }
     },
    series: [
    {
        name: 'Hours',
        pointStart: startingUTC,
        pointInterval: 24*60*60*1000, 
        data: TaskDuration
    }, 
    { 
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Regression Line',
        data: [[myStartDate, 216], [myEndDate, 50]],
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 0
            }
        },
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }]
  });

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JwmuT/8/

The goal is to create a Highchart line with starting point from X-Value 26th January and with the end point on the X-Value 7th February. Corresponding Y-Values are "260" and "0".

How to create a simple line with these to points in HighCharts? Maybe Highcharts is able to do a linear regression on the fly?!

I have [found this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-regression) but I do not know how to pass correctly X-Values in the Date format.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts doesn't calculate any type of regression or trend lines. In example you have posted, data is calculated before, and Highcharts just displays that. However there is known plugin for trendline: https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/highcharts_trendline